# Highlight problems upon hover and selection of a checkbox within divs

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with highlighting on divs. When I hover on a div, it works, as it toggles the css to highlight it upon hovering on it and upon mouse exit. But, when a click event occurs, the div still is able to be highlighted on hover even if I have statements that disallow it from doing so inside the hover function.

Here is my jQuery code tackling the upon hover on/off and upon click events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.a-choice').click(function() {
    if( !($(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) ){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight_selected');
        $(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    }

    else if( $(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked") ){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight_selected');
        $(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.a-choice').hover(function () {
    if( !($(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) ){
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight_hover");
    }

    else if( $(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked") ){
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight_hover");
    }
});
});
```

For a visual, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djleonardo/R2JDT/

Comment: In your hover callback function, that if and else if are doing the exact same thing but using opposite conditions... I'm pretty confused about that one. However, you can add this to the start of the function to kill it if the box is checked: `if($(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length === 1) return false;`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/R2JDT/1/

Comment: ...and to make your highlight_selected class persist over the top of the hover class, add `!important` to the end of your background definition

Comment: The elseif condition fires (supposed to) when a checkbox (that's within a div) is already selected, enabling it to toggle the highlight_hover class again to remove it. Does that make sense? :))

Comment: @scrowler The !important worked! Thank you! Wished you could've answered below so I could've marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

I would suggest you to use the CSS pseudo-class `hover` instead, the following approach allows you to color the div to blue when the checkbox is checked, in addition, it simplifies the logic in your javascript.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R2JDT/4/)

#### CSS

Replace your css rules

```
.highlight_selected{
    background: #bed5ed;
}

.highlight_hover{
    ...
}
```

with the following:

```
.a-choice.highlight_selected, .a-choice.highlight_selected:hover {
    background: #bed5ed;
}

.a-choice:hover{
    ...
}
```

#### JS

Remove the following code from the js file (the hover event will be handled by CSS):

```
$('.a-choice').hover(function () {
    if( !($(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) ){
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight_hover");
    }

    else if( $(this).children('.a-box').find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked") ){
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight_hover");
    }
});
```

Comment: This solves the problem above, but now, it doesn't color the div blue when it's selected.

Comment: For your reference, I have updated the answer to give an approach using the CSS pseudo-class `hover`, this will give the desired result and it simplifies the logic in JS.